# Batch script install to install and uninstall .net

Tags: .net, windows, batch-file, vbscript

I've recently been tasked with creating a batch script that will uninstall then reinstall .net 4.3.2. I've recently been learning how to create batch scripts. But I'm not sure how to create a batch script that could install a program. I'v tried searching online with no luck. Could anyone give me information on how to do this?

Comment: i dont know a .net 4.3.2 - however - if you know the command line to reinstall .net (may difference on different OPs) - just copy them into a .bat file - if you are executing the bat - the commands are beeing executed one by one... - On newer servers you have to use the commands described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831809.aspx
For older systems use the MSI parameters

Answer (score 1):

Follow advice from @Cadburry. Here is code that I use for adding roles. Add something similar to uninstall role(s) and edit this as needed for your purpose.

```
FOR /F "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%A in ('VER') DO SET WindowsVersion=%%A%%B
SET "WindowsFeatures=Web-Static-Content, Web-Dir-Browsing, Web-Http-Errors, Web-Asp, Web-Asp-Net, Web-Http-Logging, Web-Stat-Compression, Web-Basic-Auth, Web-Windows-Auth, Web-Mgmt-Console, Web-Mgmt-Service, NET-Framework-Core, PowerShell-ISE, Desktop-Experience"
REM Add more for Server 2012 R2 and Win 8.1
IF %WindowsVersion% GTR 61 SET "WindowsFeatures=%WindowsFeatures%, Web-Net-Ext45, Web-Asp-Net45
ECHO(%WindowsFeatures%
POWERSHELL.EXE -Command "&{Import-Module ServerManager; Add-WindowsFeature %WindowsFeatures%}"
```